# Periodic boundary conditions with multiple variables

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I am trying to numerically solve the following first order coupled differential equations numerically, where `i` is an integer (can be set to zero), `le = 1`, `lb = 1`, `c = 0.5`, and `Ly` is taken to be 10. I am receiving the error that

> Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable.
>   Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.

It seems that no matter how I try to impose periodicity on the solution it returns the error. Does someone know how to impose periodic boundary conditions on this type of PDE?

```
i = 0; le = 1; lb = 1; c = 0.5; Ly = 10;

NDSolve[{(-I)*D[ψ1[x, y, z, t], t] + (c + 1)*((-I)*D[ψ1[x, y, z, t], z] - (t*ψ1[x, y, z, t])/le^2) + 
     ((-I)*D[ψ2[x, y, z, t], x] + (y/lb^2)*ψ2[x, y, z, t] - D[ψ2[x, y, z, t], y]) == 10^(-3), 
   (-I)*D[ψ2[x, y, z, t], t] + (c - 1)*((-I)*D[ψ2[x, y, z, t], z] - (t*ψ2[x, y, z, t])/le^2) + 
     (-I)*D[ψ1[x, y, z, t], x] + (y/lb^2)*ψ1[x, y, z, t] + D[ψ1[x, y, z, t], y] == 10^(-3), 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ1[x, y, z, t], y == -((Ly*((100 - i)/100))/2), 
    Function[y, y + Ly*((100 - i)/100)]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ2[x, y, z, t], 
    y == -((Ly*((100 - i)/100))/2), Function[y, y + Ly*((100 - i)/100)]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ1[x, y, z, t], x == -((2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100)))), 
    Function[x, x + (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(Ly*((100 - i)/100)))]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ2[x, y, z, t], 
    x == -((2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100)))), 
    Function[x, x + (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(Ly*((100 - i)/100)))]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ1[x, y, z, t], 
    t == (Ly*((100 - i)/100))/2, Function[t, t - Ly*((100 - i)/100)]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ2[x, y, z, t], t == (Ly*((100 - i)/100))/2, 
    Function[t, t - Ly*((100 - i)/100)]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ1[x, y, z, t], 
    z == (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100))), Function[z, z - (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(Ly*((100 - i)/100)))]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[ψ2[x, y, z, t], z == (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100))), 
    Function[z, z - (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(Ly*((100 - i)/100)))]]}, {ψ1[x, y, z, t], ψ2[x, y, z, t]}, 
  {x, (-2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100))), (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100)))}, 
  {y, ((-Ly)*((100 - i)/100))/2, (Ly*((100 - i)/100))/2}, {z, (-2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100))), 
   (2*Pi*20)/(lb^2*(2*Ly*((100 - i)/100)))}, {t, ((-Ly)*((100 - i)/100))/2, (Ly*((100 - i)/100))/2}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}]
```

Comment: You may be interested in: [Implementing periodic boundary conditions in `NDSolve`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153619/27951). More in general, there are [a few questions on this site on this very topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22periodic+boundary+conditions%22+%5Bdifferential-equations%5D+hasaccepted%3Ayes); you may want to go through those too.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to add initial conditions like

```
\[Psi]1[x, y, z, 0] == 0, \[Psi]2[x, y, z, 0] == 0
```

Then, the method option should be something like:

```
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}}
```

You could also consider not using the FEM and have periodic boundary conditions of the form

```
\[Psi]1[xLeft, y, z, t] == \[Psi]1[xRight, y, z, t]
```